# How to return a pointer from recursive function, which converts polish notation to reverse polish notation?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, recursion, postfix-notation

a friend of mine was given an assignment to write a function to convert a polish notation to a reverse polish notation, so at the end a string: "sin * - x 4 + 8 3", should be converted to: "x 4 - 8 3 + * sin". There are some constraints, so for example: at the end a pointer should be returned with a memory allocated on the heap, a function prototype should contain only one argument and it should be the original string. I know that using a static variable is a horrible crime against a humanity, but despite that the very best thing we came out with is:

```
char * prefix2postfix( char ppn_in[] ){

    if (ppn_in[0] == '\0') {
        return ppn_in;
    }

    int i = 0; 
    char *left = "",
         *root = "";

    while (ppn_in[i] == ' ') i++;

    if (is_num(ppn_in[i]) || is_var(ppn_in[i])) {
        char tmp[8];
        memset(tmp, '\0', 7);
        tmp[0] = ' ';
        tmp[1] = ppn_in[i];
        root = tmp;
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (is_op(ppn_in[i])) {
        switch (ppn_in[i]) {
            case '+':
                root = " +";
                break;
            case '-':
                root = " -";
                break;
            case '*':
                root = " *";
                break;
            case '/':
                root = " /";
                break;
        }
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sqrt", 4) == 0) {
        root = " sqrt";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 4);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sqr", 3) == 0) {
        root = " sqr";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3); 
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sin", 3) == 0) {
        root = " sin";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3); 
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "cos", 3) == 0) {
        root = " cos";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "tan", 3) == 0) {
        root = " tan";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "log", 3) == 0) {
        root = " log";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    }   


    printf("reached end of the function\n");

    static char buff[200];
    buff[199] = '\0';

    strcpy(buff, left); 
    strcat(buff, root);
    return buff;
}
```

The problem is (and it is probably not the only one) that i do not know how to end the function properly so that the line `printf("reached end of the function\n");` is called only once, in that case I would be able to use `malloc` because else I would end up with memory leaks. Any suggestions are appreciated!

**EDIT**

I've tried to come with something on my own, do i end up creating memory leaks?
(I know it is very inefficient, but I allocate 200 bytes, copy them to a new buffer and after I used the value I call free)

```
char * prefix2postfix( char ppn_in[] ){

    if (ppn_in[0] == '\0') {
        return ppn_in;
    }

    int i = 0; 
    char *left = "",
         *root = "";

    while (ppn_in[i] == ' ') i++;

    if (is_num(ppn_in[i]) || is_var(ppn_in[i])) {
        char tmp[8];
        memset(tmp, '\0', 7);
        tmp[0] = ' ';
        tmp[1] = ppn_in[i];
        root = tmp;
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (is_op(ppn_in[i])) {
        switch (ppn_in[i]) {
            case '+':
                root = " +";
                break;
            case '-':
                root = " -";
                break;
            case '*':
                root = " *";
                break;
            case '/':
                root = " /";
                break;
        }
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sqrt", 4) == 0) {
        root = " sqrt";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 4);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sqr", 3) == 0) {
        root = " sqr";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3); 
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sin", 3) == 0) {
        root = " sin";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3); 
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "cos", 3) == 0) {
        root = " cos";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "tan", 3) == 0) {
        root = " tan";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "log", 3) == 0) {
        root = " log";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    }   

    char * buff = malloc(200);
    buff[199] = '\0';

    strcpy(buff, left); 
    strcat(buff, root);

    if(*left != '\0')
        free(left);

    return buff;
}
```

Comment: You either need to pass a buffer to write the result or have it dynamically allocate from free store.  How is the caller using this?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis he takes the result and assigns it to a char pointer and after he used it he calls 'free'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parsing is not quite doing recursion with two branches, but to answer your question, you need to malloc for the return value each time or the caller would not know when to free.  I am keeping the example as C code because I didn't see any C++ in your question.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_num( char v ) { return isdigit( v ); }
int is_var( char v ) { return isalpha( v ); }
int is_op( char v ) { return ispunct( v ); }

char * prefix2postfix( char ppn_in[] ){

    if (ppn_in[0] == '\0') {
        char * ptr = malloc( sizeof( char ) * 1024 );
        ptr[0] = '\0';
        return ptr;
    }

    int i = 0; 
    char tmp[16];
    char *left = 0,
         *root = "";

    while (ppn_in[i] == ' ') i++;

    if ( is_var(ppn_in[i])) {
        tmp[0] = ' ';
        tmp[1] = ppn_in[i];
        char *tptr = &tmp[2];
        while( is_var(ppn_in[i + 1] ) )
            *tptr++ = ppn_in[++i];
        *tptr = '\0';
        root = tmp;
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (is_num(ppn_in[i]) || is_var(ppn_in[i])) {
        char tmp[8];
        memset(tmp, '\0', 7);
        tmp[0] = ' ';
        tmp[1] = ppn_in[i];
        root = tmp;
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (is_op(ppn_in[i])) {
        switch (ppn_in[i]) {
            case '+':
                root = " +";
                break;
            case '-':
                root = " -";
                break;
            case '*':
                root = " *";
                break;
            case '/':
                root = " /";
                break;
        }
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 1);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sqrt", 4) == 0) {
        root = " sqrt";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 4);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sqr", 3) == 0) {
        root = " sqr";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3); 
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "sin", 3) == 0) {
        root = " sin";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3); 
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "cos", 3) == 0) {
        root = " cos";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "tan", 3) == 0) {
        root = " tan";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    } else if (strncmp(ppn_in, "log", 3) == 0) {
        root = " log";
        left = prefix2postfix(ppn_in + i + 3);
    }   


    printf("reached end of the function  '%s'  '%s'\n", left ? left : "", root );

    if( left )
    {
        strcat( left, root );
        return left;
    }
    char * buff = malloc( sizeof( char ) * 1024 );
    strcpy( buff, root );
    return buff;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if( argc == 2 )
    {
        char * ptr = prefix2postfix( argv[1] );
        printf( "Result: %s\n", ptr );
        free( ptr );
    }
}
```

To do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_binary_operator( const char * token )
{
    return ( ( *token == '+' ) ||
             ( *token == '*' ) ||
             ( *token == '-' ) ||
             ( *token == '/' ) );
}

int is_unary_operator( const char * token )
{
    return ( !strcmp( token, "sin" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "cos" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "tan" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "exp" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "log" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "ln" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "sqrt" ) ||
             !strcmp( token, "sqr" ) );
}

int reverse_polish_arranger( char ** tokens, size_t cnt, size_t iter/*, size_t depth*/ )
{
    /*printf( "%*sPeeking at %s\n", depth << 1, "", tokens[iter] );*/
    if( is_binary_operator( tokens[iter] ) )
    {
        int next_pos = reverse_polish_arranger( tokens, cnt, iter + 1 /*, depth + 1 */);
        int end_pos = reverse_polish_arranger( tokens, cnt, next_pos + 1 /*, depth + 1 */);
        char * ptr = tokens[iter];
        memmove( tokens + iter, tokens + iter + 1, sizeof( char * ) * ( end_pos - iter  ) );
        tokens[end_pos] = ptr;
        return end_pos;
    }
    else if( is_unary_operator( tokens[iter] ) )
    {
        int end_pos = reverse_polish_arranger( tokens, cnt, iter + 1 /*, depth + 1*/ );
        char * ptr = tokens[iter];
        memmove( tokens + iter, tokens + iter + 1, sizeof( char * ) * ( end_pos - iter ) );
        tokens[end_pos] = ptr;
        return end_pos;
    }
    else
        return iter;
}

char * reverse_polish( const char * expr )
{
    size_t index;
    size_t push_index = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    char * result = 0;
    char * buffer = 0;
    char ** pointers = 0;

    /* Prepare the workspace. */
    if( !expr )
        return 0;
    len = strlen( expr );
    if( !( result = malloc( sizeof( char ) * len ) ) )
        return 0;
    if( !( buffer = malloc( sizeof( char ) * len ) ) )
    {
        free( result );
        return 0;
    }
    if( !( pointers = malloc( sizeof( char * ) * len ) ) )
    {
        free( result );
        free( buffer );
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy( buffer, expr );
    memset( pointers, 0, sizeof( char * ) * len );

    /* Cheap tokenize using space a delimiter. */
    pointers[push_index++] = buffer;
    for( index = 0; index < len; ++index )
        if( buffer[index] == ' ' )
            buffer[index++] = '\0', pointers[push_index++] = &buffer[index];

    /* printf( "Before:\n" );
     * for( index = 0; index < push_index; ++index )
     *    printf( "Token %3d: %s\n", index, pointers[index] );
     */

    /* Do the conversion. */
    reverse_polish_arranger( pointers, push_index, 0/*, 0*/ );

    /*
     * printf( "After:\n" );
     * for( index = 0; index < push_index; ++index )
     *    printf( "Token %3d: %s\n", index, pointers[index] );
     */

    /* Prepare output buffer. */
    result[0] = '\0';
    for( index = 0; index < push_index; ++index )
        strcat( strcat( result, pointers[index] ), " " );

    /* Cleanup temporary workspace */
    free( pointers );
    free( buffer );

    /* Return new string. */
    return result;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if( argc == 2 )
    {
        char * reversed = reverse_polish( argv[1] );
        if( reversed )
        {
            printf( "Reverse: %s\n", reversed );
            free( reversed );
        }
        else
            printf( "Failed to reverse: %s\n", argv[1] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
./a.out "sin * - x 4 + 8 3"
Reverse: x 4 - 8 3 + * sin
```

Comment: yeah, you are right, I've started with left and right and then I removed right and other variables left as they were. I thought of it as a tree problem at first and I couldn't solve it, so I ended up with my result. Am i getting it right? You acquire a buffer for left in the last step and prevent to get to the end of the function to the last buffer until the end? But when do you free left?

Comment: I free left in main because it is ultimately returned by the function or I reuse what was allocated from the lower-call on the recursion.

Comment: You are somewhat on the right track, but you are not parsing correctly because you are reversing the arguments making the subtraction inverted.  You only wanted to juxtapose the operator.

Comment: @orustammanapov I am giving you another solution that you could study.